# Override bootstrap modal close transition effect to fadeout slow

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

for design sake, I customize `Bootstrap modal transition` to something like the code below but when closing the modal, it disappears quickly without transition. Question is, How can I add a transition fading out effect when closing all modals? Any help would be much appreciated.

CSS:

```
.fade-custom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .30s linear;
  -o-transition: all .30s linear;
  transition: all .30s linear;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.fade-custom.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Note: I tried jquery to handle fadeOut but no luck.

```
$( ".close-help" ).click(function() {
  $( "#helpReviewers" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

Demo:

```css
.fade-custom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .30s linear;
  -o-transition: all .30s linear;
  transition: all .30s linear;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.fade-custom.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade-custom" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close " data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Princesodhi add working demo. See post thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this CSS

```
.fade-custom {
  -webkit-transition: all .30s linear !important ;
  -o-transition: all .30s linear !important ;
  transition: all .30s linear !important ;
  transform: scale(0) !important ;
}

.fade.in {
  transform: scale(1) !important ;
}
```

also don't remove `fade` class from HTML code. otherwise, the bootstrap effect will not work.

**DEMO HERE**  https://jsfiddle.net/9w0gstq4/

Comment: Cool! Thanks bro. will try this.

Comment: Tried but without removing the `fade` class, the modal will slide down and up

Comment: did u write !important in css? as it is here https://jsfiddle.net/9w0gstq4/

Comment: It works now but it slides a bit and it's fast. How to remove that slide and adjust the time?

Comment: hmm. try to generate gif file or update jsfiddle. I will try to fix it. 

use "ScreenToGif 1.4.2"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147072/discussion-between-claudios-and-prince-sodhi).